# what is this question asking for? basic metric concepts

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am studying basic concepts of metrics. and I ve been practicing axioms of metrics to prove some functions can be metrics or not. then this question showed up and I do not understand what am I being asked for. how is related to axioms of metric? am i supposed to find a function? 

$X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $(\alpha ,\beta)\in R^2$. Define $d_{\alpha\beta}$ as a function on $X\times X$ such that $d_{\alpha\beta}(a,b)=1$ and $d_{\alpha\beta}(b,c)=\alpha$ and $d_{\alpha\beta}(c,a)=\beta$. Find all possible $(\alpha,\beta) $ s.t $d_{\alpha\beta}$ is a metric.

Comment: Does this paraphrase of the question help? "Let $d$ be a metric on a set $X$ with three elements, $a$, $b$, and $c$. if $d(a, b) = 1$, what are the possible values for $d(b, c)$ and $d(c, a)$?"